# VS2010 F5 is available but Ctrl F5 is invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I encountered a hell problem when I attempted to invoke “LoadLibrary” in C# environment. The application was crashed when I pressed “Ctrl + F5” and entered the directly running environment, but it was certainly O.K. if I pressed “F5” entering the debug mode. I tried to directly run the application, it had the same errors. There are some test projects in attach files, I thought that it was enough describing the issue. How did I solve it?

**Ps:** The solution’s environment must be set to “Debug” and the compile form must be “X64”, then the ConsoleApplication2 project is “Startup project”.

I tried to use the “LibraryEssential” project to invoking the “MathmaticPower” function which was in “MathmaticLibrary” project. But my C# project “ConsoleApplication2” loaded “LibraryEssential” dll file by “PInvoke LoadLibrary”.

**Some improvements**: I tried to run the C# exe application in "Administrator", It's O.K., but I run it with other user, it's failed! Shall I must run the application in administrator role? I don't want to do so. Have any other ways for the issue?

attach files: [LoadLibrary.zip](https://ftf-248.yousendit.com/download/1/04D3FB32693FD51B/8b10cd07266f297a0ee7042ee494b0bd770d55a3/LoadLibrary.zip?download_id=3819940999&user_locale=en&id=1461889965&ufid=04D3FB32693FD51B&file=LoadLibrary.zip)

Comment: Use the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event to report crashes.  Display or log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString() in the event handler.  Post the stack trace of the exception you get in your question if that doesn't help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Hans, I tried the UnhandleException event, it can't catch the exception when the application has crashed, I viewed the event viewer in administration tools, and get following event content:

Comment: Faulting application name: ConsoleApplication2.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5019d80d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c40f2
Faulting process id: 0x1458
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd704e58fdd310
Faulting application path: D:\LiLin\LoadLibraryTest\LoadLibrary\ConsoleApplication2\bin\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 97cd28aa-dc41-11e1-afa6-005056c00008

Comment: The DLL you are loading is corrupting the heap.  Send it back where it came from, you definitely don't want to load it.